# Copy Mat in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I try to copy a image to other image using opencv, but I got a problem. Two image is not the same, like this:

[image]

This is the code I used:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>

#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
int main()
{
    cv::Mat inImg =    cv::imread("C:\\Users\\DUY\\Desktop\\basic_shapes.png");  
    //Data point copy  
    unsigned char * pData = inImg.data;  

    int width = inImg.rows;  
    int height = inImg.cols;  

    cv::Mat outImg(width, height, CV_8UC1);  
    //data copy using memcpy function  
    memcpy(outImg.data, pData, sizeof(unsigned char)*width*height);  

   //processing and copy check  
   cv::namedWindow("Test");  
   imshow("Test", inImg);  

   cv::namedWindow("Test2");  
   imshow("Test2", outImg);  

   cvWaitKey(0);  
}
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Simply use `.clone()` function of `cv::Mat`:

```
cv::Mat source = cv::imread("basic_shapes.png");
cv::Mat dst = source.clone();
```

This will do the trick. 
   You are making an image with one channel only (which means only shades of gray are possible) with `CV_8UC1`, you could use `CV_8UC3` or `CV_8UC4` but for simply copying stick with the clone function.

Comment: Which one better option either clone or copyTo of image?

Answer (score 5):

You actually don't want to copy the data, since you start with a RGB `CV_8UC3` image, and you want to work on a grayscale `CV_8UC1` image.

You should use `cvtColor`, that will convert your RGB data into grayscale.

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat inImg = cv::imread("C:\\Users\\DUY\\Desktop\\basic_shapes.png"); // inImg is CV_8UC3 
    Mat outImg;
    cvtColor(inImg, outImg, COLOR_RGB2GRAY); // Now outImg is CV_8UC1

    //processing and copy check  
    imshow("Test", inImg);  
    imshow("Test2", outImg);  
    waitKey();  
}
```

With a simple `memcopy` you're copying a sequence of `uchar` like this:

```
BGR BGR BGR BGR  ...
```

into an image that expects them to be (G for gray):

```
G G G G ...
```

and that's is causing your `outImg` to be uncorrect.

Your code will be correct if you define `outImage` like:

```
cv::Mat outImg(width, height, CV_8UC3);  // Instead of CV_8UC1
```

Answer (score 3):

the best way is to use the opencv [clone](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-clone) method:

```
cv::Mat outImg = inImg.clone();
```

Comment: thank for your help, but I want to use Mat.data as an array of unsigned char. I need to do something ralated to this

Comment: in that case you might need to convert to CV_8UC3 format, that's more complicated...

Comment: open cv has functions to convert matrices between data types (8UC1 -> 8UC3, 8UC3 -> 8UC1, etc). You need to make sure that before you use a raw pointer to the matrix data you have converted that matrix to the data type you will use the pointer as.

Answer (score 2):

Your original image is in color. `cv::Mat outImg(width, height, CV_8UC1);` says that your new image is of data type `CV_8UC1` which is an 8-bit grayscale image. So you know that is not correct. Then you try to copy the amount of data from the original image to the new image that corresponds to `total pixels * 8-bits` which is at best 1/3 of the actual image (assuming the original image was 3 color, 8-bits per color, aka a 24-bit image) and perhaps even 1/4 (if it had an alpha channel, making it 4 channels of 8-bits or a 32-bit image).

TLDR: you're matrices aren't the same type, and you are making assumptions about the size of the data to be copied off of an incorrect, and incorrectly sized type.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple code to copy image.

```
 #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>  
 #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>  
 #include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>  
 #include <cmath> 
 int main()  
 {  
    cv::Mat inImg = cv::imread("1.jpg");  

    cv::Mat outImg = inImg.clone();   

   cv::namedWindow("Test");  
   imshow("Test", inImg);

   cv::namedWindow("Test2");  
   imshow("Test2", outImg);

   cvWaitKey(0);  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Mat source = imread("1.png", 0);
Mat dest;
source.copyTo(dest);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.